# How do I change the Minecraft version in a Forge environment?

Tags: scala, development-environment, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So there's this abandoned open source scala mod I wanna maintain and it's currently on Minecraft 1.10.2. How do I upgrade to Minecraft 1.11? I got the build.gradle from the forge mdk .zip but that broke everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the Forge version, **DO NOT copy directly from the MDK .zip!** If the mod uses scala or kotlin, or non-standard source dirs, that **will** break the mod!

First, you'll need to restore the original build.gradle, if you still have access to it. Given that it's an open source mod, I assume you do.

Then, to change the version, you'll need to do a few things.

The first thing you'll need to do is change the `version` field in the `minecraft` block to the new forge version. So e.g. if it's `version = "1.10.2-12.18.1.2011"`, you want to change it to `version = "1.11-13.19.0.2162"`. You get this value from the MDK build.gradle.

Another thing you'll need to change is the `mappings` field. E.g. if it's `mappings = "snapshot_20160518"`, you want to change it to `mappings = "snapshot_20161111"`. You also get this value from the MDK build.gradle.

Then, you should look at the `buildscript` block in the two build.gradle. It should have a nested block that looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.2-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

If the ForgeGradle version looks different between them, you need to change it.

Finally, you should update all the dependencies, in the `dependencies` block.

After you're done tweaking the build.gradle, all you need to do is run `gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace` or `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace`, and re-run the IDE command (`gradlew.bat eclipse` or `./gradlew eclipse` for eclipse, `gradlew.bat idea` or `./gradlew idea` for IDEA, etc).